# How to manage user access in Janusgraph Version 0.5.3

Tags: janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using Janusgraph Version 0.5.3 with CS and ES, which has gremlin 3.4.6.
I am able to create 2 graphs using ConfiguredGraphFactory (dev & test)

Now what i want to achive is create users (hopefully using credentailDB, where i am currently facing issues) and after i create dev users and test users, want to know if i can restrict them to have access only to specific graph, rather than all the graphs.

What i mean is ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames() should return only respective graphs for that user and not all graphs in CS.

Thanks,
Atul.

Answer (score 1):

There are no authorization functions built into `ConfiguredGraphFactory`. There may be ways to do what you are asking but none that are easily implemented without detailed knowledge of Gremlin Server internals. In TinkerPop 3.5.0 (not yet released as of the time of my answering, but it is expected within weeks), this situation changes as authorization features have been exposed. The work was done under this issue: [TINKERPOP-2389](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2389) if you'd like to learn more.